# Its possible use get_meta_tags without name?

Tags: php

My objective is extract the information from the meta tags without name, for example "charset"

The objective is extract charset and save it on a JSON File, I know how to save it but I'm pretty lost with how can I extract the meta tag without name

**The code should work or I have to change it?**

Here my code:

```
<?php
$domain = "http://www.americanairlines.de/";
$tags = get_meta_tags($domain);
echo $tags['charset'];
```

for try to take the value from here:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

but it don't works, someone can tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php. It mentions that "Only meta tags with name attributes will be parsed.". So you would need to use string matching to get desired data.

Comment: And how can I do for use string matching?

Comment: You can use function file() to get contents in an array and loop through. Then you can use function strstr to pull desired content. As soon you find your meta tag with charset you can break the loop. 

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will not get tags without a `name` attribute.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php

> Only meta tags with name attributes will be parsed. Quotes are not
>   required.

Comment: Hmm but the tags doesn't have names, so how can I do it for take the tags without name?

Comment: When I look at the page source on http://www.americanairlines.de, I do see named meta tags...

Comment: Yeah but it is only example, I've to take named tags from another web pages and the meta tag that contains "charset" doesn't have name

Answer (score 0):

How to get the named meta tags from a page:

```
$domain = "https://www.nu.nl/";      // Better example url
$tags = get_meta_tags($domain);      // Get the tags!

var_dump($tags);                      // This dumps all that's there
if isset($tags['charset']){           // You can only echo an element...
  echo $tags['charset'];              // ...if it exists (NOTE: charset in a named tag would be incorrect but if it's there it will echo it)
}
```

Please note, charset is NOT a named meta tag! charset is a meta attribute on its own. So if you're after the charset, you will need something different.